# Dropcap content does not match html

Tags: css, character, html

I'm trying to put a dropcap in a paragraph by using a . I think I found the correct workflow and tested it already in another area of my website, it worked great. When I want to apply the same technique to the desired paragraph, the content, the first letter of the paragraph, changes when viewed in browser to "03/". I've tried several different options but always same outcome.. When I inspect element in chrome, it shows "03/" as content, which is not correct. Does anyone know what might cause this?

css:

```
#services .firstcharacter {    /*displays /03 instead of character*/
    float: left; 
    color: #000; 
    font-size: 75px; 
    line-height: 80px; 
    padding-top: 4px; 
    padding-right: 8px; 
    padding-left: 3px; 
    font-family: Georgia; }
```

html:

```
<p><span class="firstcharacter">N</span>ulla...</p>
```

[paragraph screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102887109/Dropcap%20content%20issue.jpg)

Thanks!

EXTRA INFO

At first I removed #services, but no changes.. Afterwards I wrote code differently like this:

CSS

```
.service p.char a{
    float: left; 
    color: #000; 
    font-size: 75px; 
    line-height: 80px; 
    padding-top: 4px; 
    padding-right: 8px; 
    padding-left: 3px; 
    font-family: serif;
}
```

HTML

```
<p class="char"><a><span>D</span></a>ulla...</p>
```

But nothing changed.

When I inspect the element in browser (chrome), the span's content has changed to 03/. But when I change it there, the character "D" or whatever is displayed correctly.

Can't really see where this error might be.. I checked my entire code for the "03/" combination as well and changed font settings, but no luck there either.

Comment: Try removing #services

Comment: Smells like a charset issue...

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know full code, I can only suggest you removing `#services` from css. Or add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to `<head>`. Or both.

Comment: I tried different things, but all with same outcome.. Charset was already defined to UTF-8.

>> edited original question

Answer (score 0):

By dropping the  in html, I solved the problem..

Now I have my solution, but would still like to know why this happened.
Thanks for the replies and for helping me find the cause.